# Can't change text style in word

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I got a word document that has a few headings, but for some reason after i type content it automatically becomes a heading and i can't change it back t simple text (so it will appear wrong lettertype/size and shows up in the table of contents)

I select the text (orange) and then click the left most style but it keeps reverting to heading#2 a second later no matter what i do. The Red areas are the proper style and blue is heading 3 and the yellow block a heading2.

Is there a way to stop word from automatically changing the headings of texts? or at least allow me to change it to the proper one? Because i can click "standaard" all i want, but it keeps reverting back to Kop2

[image]

Comment: You will need to post somewhere a small example document to be analyzed.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try:

1. copy a few words from where it's red, and paste that just before the orange/after the blue with "keep source formatting"
2. cut all of the orange, and paste it in the middle of the red that you just pasted with "keep text only"
3. delete the words from the red that you pasted, so it's just the words from the orange that you pasted.

Does that fix the formatting?

Comment: Actually that's how i am currently already doing it(solution1) so yes it does work but there should be an easier way right? Like why does selecting the correct style not just work :|

Comment: It's hard to tell without an example document, as @harrymc says. Have you tried closing and opening the document? Turning your pc off and on again? Word can be buggy sometimes

Answer (score 0):

### There are three kinds of styles possibly involved: Paragraph, Character, and Linked.

Here is [my writing on these](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Character) three.

In the paragraph that you do not want to be a heading style, click in the paragraph. Do *not* select anything. Change that to the body-text level paragraph style that you want.

If the style you are trying to apply is a linked style, and you attempt to apply it to selected text within a paragraph, you will copy the font formatting of the style but it will retain the underlying paragraph formatting originally applied. *I almost always keep linked styles disabled.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an easier way. I run into this issue a lot as I edit papers for a journal and they come from various sources. Finally figured it out: unfold the Styles Pane in Word, and you will see the current style used where you placed your cursor. From the drop-down menu select Clear Formatting!

[image]